# Graph Editor - Active curve name?

Tags: graph-editor

I often have tons of keyframes for tons of things in the scene. Sometimes I have a key selected in the graph editor but I just don't know which object this key belongs to. Any idea how to check the active key object name fast? Scrolling the object list on the left shows nothing, if there is any highlighted name I can never find it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As generally we select the object we want to edit, and then operate, this seems a non-well implemented function.

This is the fastest way I've found:

Box select all the objects in the graph editor list, press numpad + three times (until every channel is expanded, press - to collapse).

Select the point you want to edit and press shift H to hide everything else (Alt H to unhide).

The corresponding channel will be the only one with the eye icon active.

[image]